# QtScript - calling slots from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtscript

I have an application that uses QtScript. The QtScript is executed in seperated thread, this means that if I want to access slots from main threads widgets, I need some sort of sinhronization. In C++ this can easy be done with this: [invokeMethod](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#913fb94dd61f1a62fc809f8d842c3afa) .

As the qtscript uses some internal abstraction to bind javascript with c++ clases it leads me to think that it could be through the same invokeMethod. This would mean that threads are propely synhronized if I call slots from different threads, but if I don't, I will get random crashes, probabliy only when the application will be in production. If I don't trust qtscript, I have to write a Wrapper, that is called and invokes all methods with invokeMethod call, which is bad too..

The question is: Are qtscript slot invocation propely synhronized and how to check this? (I'm running on windows with Qt5.1 )